# How to display JS function of google/code-prettify onkeyup event

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

This's my code for adding eventListener of google/code-prettify **what I want to achieve is displaying the code as a code when the user insert his code in the textarea** it should be working but for some reason it doesn't

```
<body onload="PR.prettyPrint()">
    <h1>Insert your code</h1>

    <form method="POST">

        <pre class="  prettyprint"> <code class=" prettyprint">   <?php echo htmlspecialchars($str); ?>      </code></pre>
        <div class="  prettyprint"> <textarea id="testcode" class=" prettyprint" id="code"> </textarea></div>

        <script lang="javascript">
            document.getElementById("testcode").addEventListener('onkeyup', PR.prettyPrint, false);
            document.getElementById("testcode").innerText = "echo";
        </script>
        <input type="submit"></input>

    </form>
</body>
```

The textarea and an example of printed code using the lib.

[image: textare]

**Documentation** [Documentation](https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify)
If you are calling prettyPrint via an event handler, wrap it in a function. Instead of doing:

```
addEventListener('load', PR.prettyPrint, false);
```

wrap it in a closure like:

```
addEventListener('onkeyup', function(event) { PR.prettyPrint(); }, false);
```

Comment: you have double `id` attribute use `class` instead. ❌`id="testcode" id="code"` ✅`class="testcode prettyprint code"` or only one id. I hope this helps

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas It's different tag but it doesn;t work though.

Comment: I understand I changed to one id and it prints `echo` but doesn't prettify the text.

Comment: Steve I posted now an alternative solution (only 5 lines of code), however if you want google library the bug was ❌ `onkeyup` to ✅ `keyup`... see the answer and tell me if solved the problem or not

Comment: added now also a GIF and code with the new library. I hope is what you want

Answer (score 0):

### alternative library

I used a similar library that is much better.

and is named [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/)

---

I highly suggest not using the google library because is an archived project

[image]

it may have a lot of bugs not fixed

---

✅ this code have only 5 lines of JS code!

[image]

> GIF example code in javascript, but you can use PHP or any other language you want (just see the docs)

```js
const inputArea = document.querySelector("textarea");
const outputArea = document.querySelector("pre code");

inputArea.addEventListener("input", () => {
  outputArea.innerHTML = inputArea.value;
  hljs.highlightElement(outputArea);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@11.6.0/build/styles/default.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@11.6.0/build/highlight.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <pre><code class="language-javascript"></code></pre>
</form>
```

---

**benefits:**

- open-source/maintained until now.
- you can choose themes (240 in total)
- if you really want, you can create your own theme, with CSS only
- 190 languages syntax highlighting.
- similar API to the google library

```html
<pre><code class="language-js">...</code></pre>
```

so see their docs on how to use it https://highlightjs.org/usage/